# Hibernate select hql can't get a current result

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

They're my entities:

```
    @Entity
    public class Item {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;

        private String name;

        @ManyToOne
        private Users users;

        public Item(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Item() {
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Users getUsers() {
            return users;
        }

        public void setUsers(Users users) {
            this.users = users;
        }
    }

//@Audited
//@Filter(name = "selectUsername", condition = "")
@NamedQueries(
        @NamedQuery(
                name = "getUserByName", query = "select u from Users u where name = :name",timeout = 60000
        )
)
@Entity
@Cacheable
@Cache(
        usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE
)
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private int age;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "users")
//    @OrderColumn
    private List<Item> items;

    public Users(String name, int age, String info) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.info = info;
    }

    public Users() {
    }

//    @NotAudited
    private String info;

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public void setInfo(String info) {
        this.info = info;
    }
}
```

and this is my test Class:

```
@Test
    public void f() {
        Session session = HibernateHelper.getSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("select u from Users u join u.items i on i.id>4");
        List<Users> o = query.getResultList();
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }
```

and I think I will get a list contain only two users which has two items, but beyond my image, I get this:

[image]

and this is my database:

[image]

Comment: Can you try something like:
`select u from Users u join u.items i having i.id > 4`

Comment: I've resloved this problem, I used where rather than on,and i finally get the differents between two words in mysql,and thanks you for your help